# Find tags with text inside

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this text string

```
<div><div>Content</div><div><span>Searching</span></div></div>
```

And I'm searching for `div` tag which have text `Searching` inside them. So I need regex which will match

```
<div><span>Searching</span></div>
```

Closest what I got is with

```
<div>(.*?)Searching(.*?)<\/div>
```

but it matches from the first `div` and result is

```
<div><div>Content</div><div><span>Searching</span></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `<div><([a-zA-Z]+?)>Searching<\/([([a-zA-Z]+?)><\/div>`

Comment: I think parsing html and using dom in better than regex.

Comment: You can't reliably parse markup with regex! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127  Try DOMDocument and DOMXPath instead.

Comment: @GordonM I see now my mistake, but I don'ttrying to parse html or xhtml, just used this as example. I have starting string, ending string and word between those two strings (but can also have more random text between). And just need to find smallest match, because there can be multiple starting and ending strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a negative look-ahead should do it for you:

```
<div>((?:(?!<div>).)*)Searching(.*?)<\/div>
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/11kzm2/1).

Answer (score 0):

You should try X-path,
If this question are put on Perl then sure i will help you, But i will give you Perl code may be this one helpful for you

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $dir = 'd:/00Tools/Testing/gui';  #set any dir path
    foreach my $grep_file (glob("$dir/*.htm"))  # get all .htm file inside folder
    {
        my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $grep_file);
        my $nodeset = $xp->find('/html/body/div//div/span'); # find span in this situation
        foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist)
        {
            my $final_th_node = XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
            if ($final_th_node =~ /<span>Searching<\/span>/)    #test our conditon
                {
                    print "true";
                }
            else
                {
                    print "false";
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to upvote this because it suggests using the appropriate parsing libraries (equivalent to PHP DOMDocument and DOMXpath, presumably) instead of regex, but I can't because the example is in the wrong language for the question.